# Вставка новых узлов в односвязаный список на javascript

Tags: javascript

Рубрика "помогите инвалиду". Нужен метод для вставки нового узла в середину односвязного списка. Застрял на таком этапе (UPD: самодостаточная часть кода):

```
// превращает массив в список
function arrayToList()
{
    var number;
    var list = {number: number, next: list};

    for (var i = arrayToList.arguments.length; i > -1; i--)
    {
        if (i < arrayToList.arguments.length - 1)
            list = {number: arrayToList.arguments[i], next: list};
        else
            list = {number: arrayToList.arguments[i], next: null};
    }

    return list;
}

var list = arrayToList(1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12);

// должна вставлять 6 между 5 и 7, но не вставляет
function insert(node, list)
{    
    if (list.number < node && list.next.number > node) // вставка в середину
    {
        var newnode = {number: node, next: list.next};
        list.next = newnode;
        return list;
    }
    else if (list.number == node) // узел уже есть
        return "node " + node + " already exists in the list!";
    else if (list.next != null)
        return insert(node, list.next); // собственно, источник проблемы
    else // вставка в конец
    {
        var newnode = {number: node, next: null};
        list.next = newnode;
        return list;
    }
}

console.log(insert(6, list));
```

Все работает, но не очень: вместо всего списка возвращается та его часть, которая начинается с узла, идущего перед тем, который я собираюсь вставить. Т.е. вместо узел1 - узел2 - ... - узел(n-1) - узел(n) - ... возвращается только узел(n-1) - узел(n) - ... (где узел(n) - вставляемый узел). Дело в рекурсивном вызове, который каждый раз запускает функцию с укороченным списком. Проблему понял, но решения не нашел (( Оправдана ли рекурсия вообще? Может, можно как-то циклом? Или как-то запоминать весь список от начала до конца? Нужна помощь.

Comment: что за list? как вызывается эта функция?

Comment: @Grundy это не функция, это сам список, в который нужно вставить новый узел. он (список) генерируется другим методом из массива. т.е. на входе в весь этот цирк - массив. из него - список, а в список нужно добавлять (и удалять, но это следующий непростой этап)

Comment: @Grundy т.е. да, list - это список, аргумент этой функции, а сама она вызывается как-то Link.insert()

Comment: `function insert(node, list)` - это функция. Как она вызывается? что ей передается. пример вызова?

Comment: добавь [mcve] чтобы можно было увидеть как это сейчас работает

Comment: самое простое решение - возвращать не результат функции, а переданный `list`

Comment: @Grundy заапдейтил текст вопроса необходимыми запчастями

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как важен только результат `insert` на первом уровне, не нужно возвращать наружу результаты внутренних вызовов, достаточно всегда возвращать переданный `list`

```js
// превращает массив в список
function arrayToList(...numbers) {
  return numbers.reduceRight(function(list, number) {
    return {
      number: number,
      next: list
    };
  }, null);
}

var list = arrayToList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);

// должна вставлять 6 между 5 и 7, но не вставляет
function insert(node, list) {
  if (list.number == node) // узел уже есть
    return "node " + node + " already exists in the list!";

  if (list.number < node && list.next.number > node || list.next == null) // вставка в середину
  {
    var newnode = {
      number: node,
      next: list.next
    };
    list.next = newnode;
  } else {
    insert(node, list.next); // собственно, источник проблемы
  }
  return list;
}

console.log(insert(6, list));
```

С циклом еще проще - бежать по списку пока не выполнены условия, добавить в нужное место новый элемент и затем вернуть переданный лист

```js
// превращает массив в список
function arrayToList(...numbers) {
  return numbers.reduceRight(function(list, number) {
    return {
      number: number,
      next: list
    };
  }, null);
}

var list = arrayToList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);

// должна вставлять 6 между 5 и 7, но не вставляет
function insert(node, list) {
  if (list.number == node) // узел уже есть
    return "node " + node + " already exists in the list!";

  var cur = list;
  while (!(cur.number < node && cur.next.number > node || cur.next == null)) cur = cur.next;
  cur.next = {
    number: node,
    next: cur.next
  }

  return list;
}

console.log(insert(6, list));
```

Comment: спасибо, Добрый человек!